# capture another camera inside a capture device source filter?

Tags: directshow

Is it possible capture another camera inside a capture device source filter?

Essentially a virtual camera that displays a "real" camera stream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and in a straightforward way: virtual source filter manages another graph internally and processes the data from embedded camera and graph.

Comment: You are right, I was able to create a filter graph on an internal thread. Thanks